# Having problems with multiplying Arrays

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     double[] temp = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
     double[] tripple = {26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50};

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = (int) Math.pow(temp[i], 2);
        }

        for (double value : temp) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }

        for (int k = 26; k < 50; k++) {
            tripple[k] = (int) Math.pow(temp[k], 3);
        }

        for (double value : tripple) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
 }
```

I have been trying to get my second array to give cubed numbers from 26 onwards. So far, I have the 1-25 working, but I can't get the last twenty five to work. I've tried everything I can think of, and what is there is the last iteration after hours of banging my head on the walls.

Comment: tripple[k] = (int) Math.pow(temp[k], 3);  Which I fixed already.

But now I get, 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26

Comment: You should definitely read, and post, the error messages you got. They tell you precisely what's wrong and where. You should get something along the lines of "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 26 at line xx". Reading the javadoc of ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, if the name isn't clear enough, explain when this exception is thrown.

Comment: I had this code before, for(int k=0;k<tripple.length;k++){}. But I got desperate enough that I changed it after many failures. 
I still cant get the latter half to come off as cubed, they come out as sqaured

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

```
for (int k = 26; k < 50; k++)
```

The indices in the array `tripple` do not go from 26 to 50, but from 0 to the length of the array.

```
for (int k = 0; k < tripple.length; k++)
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop is incorrect, because it uses *values* instead of *indexes*:

```
for (int k = 26; k < 50; k++) {
    tripple[k] = (int) Math.pow(temp[k], 3);
}
```

When you apply operator `[i]` to an array, it means "give me the element at position `i` counting from zero". It does *not* mean "give me an element whose value is `i`".

`k` needs to be from zero to `tripple.length()`, the same way the `i` goes in your first `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different arrays.
Both will start from 0.
So you need to use following in second array.

```
for(int k=0;k<tripple.length;k++){}
```

This means

```
triple[0]=26;
```

and so on.

One more thing you have used temp array in the line below

```
tripple[k] = (int) Math.pow(temp[k], 3);
```

Here values in the temp array are different.

```
temp[0]=1;
temp[1]=4;
```

and so on